# Can not connect to SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to connect to SQL Server Management Studio. My team uses the same details and are able to connect. I am new to the team.
Can anyone help me connect to it?

Edit: *As it turned out, **I do not have permission to makes changes in firewall settings** etc. I double checked from seniors, they told that no changes in such settings are required. Is there some other way? What must be going wrong?*

Edit : [Error popup on connecting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5EbXl.png) ---This is the popup I get while connecting.

[Authentication Type ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQLZq.png) --- Some other details.

I am getting following technical details--

```
===================================

Cannot connect to devsql17.mmm.com.1930.

===================================

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)

------------------------------
For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=53&LinkId=20476

------------------------------
Error Number: 53
Severity: 20
State: 0


------------------------------
Program Location:

   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo, SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean integratedSecurity)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnection owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, TimeoutTimer timeout)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(SqlConnection owningObject, TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SqlConnection owningObject, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlStudio.Explorer.ObjectExplorerService.ValidateConnection(UIConnectionInfo ci, IServerType server)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.ConnectionDlg.Connector.ConnectionThreadUser()
```

Thanksss a lot !!

Comment: Is this database hosted on the internet? if you are hosted on a VPS, check whether the server is running / firewall..

Comment: The server is running !!!!

Comment: http://support.sysonline.com/support/solutions/articles/4000016491-errmsg-a-network-related-or-instance-specific-error-occurred-while-establishing-a-connection-to-sql

Answer (score 1):

Above question is old, but I ran across similar issue today. I was able to connect to SQL locally but could not connect from within domain and outside.

The SQL Server has to have be connected to a profile with "Turn on File and Printer Sharing".

Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network and Sharing Center

OR it has to be connected in Public profile, if you are trying to connect from public network.

Try updating this setting either by connecting its network to Public or by updating the Turn on .. for sharing.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the Database Server is Running & if it does please check the firewall. You have to add a exception to 1433, to allow access over the network. And Make Sure TCP/IP is enabled on the Sql Server Configuration Manager.

[Enable Inbound and Outbound Rules To Open TCP Port 1433 For SQL Server 2012 instances](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CBIQ0mgqxGs)

[Configure Windows Firewall to Work with SQL Server](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1929/configure-windows-firewall-to-work-with-sql-server/)

Comment: I can not do above changes. More over, I have been told that I do not even need them. Any other inputs?

Comment: @Kum - Hope you are accessing over the internet, check whether the server needs a VPN to connect?

Comment: Yes, accessing over the internet. My VPN connection is up and running..

Comment: Therer really are a multitude of SQl Server connection troubleshooting guides. Press start / run and type CMD. Type `PING <yourservername>` any response? Failing that type "troubleshoot SQl Server connection" into google and follow some of those guides